# How to get path of current html?

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx

I going through various variables listed on the [Templating](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.6.4/templating.html) page of sphinx. But I am not able to get the path of current html (inside the template (`_template/layout.html`)).

Closest I got was using [rellinks](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.6.4/templating.html#rellinks). Problem is that it gives the paths of `next` and `previous` pages but not the current page.

Similarly,

`{{ file }}` gives `./.html`
`{{ pathto(pagename) }}` gives `./build/html`

I want the entire paths of an html file. eg. `./build/html/2017/10/12/somepage.html`

How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pagename](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/templating.html#pagename) will give you the path to the current file disregarding the file ending, relative to the root document of your Sphinx project. You don't need to wrap it into `pathto()`.

For example, if the current document is located at `/something/somepage.html` in the root directory,`{{ pagename }}` returns `something/somepage`.

To retrieve the actual path, use something like:

`/{{ pagename }}.html`

or:

`{{ '/' + pagename + '.html'}}`.

Comment: Works! I was trying `{{ pathto(pagename) }}`. So `pagename` is a misnomer.